AWS RDS PostgreSQL: Connection Closing and Requiring Re-authentication with New IAM Token
I’m using AWS RDS PostgreSQL with IAM authentication, where tokens expire every 15 minutes. According to AWS documentation, once a connection is opened, it shouldn’t require re-authentication even after the token expires.
Possible duplicates: Do I need to reconnect every 15 minutes with RDS IAM authentication
I’m using the following code:
public class ConnectionFactory: IConnectionFactory
{
   private readonly NpgSqlDatasource _npgSqlDatasource;

   public ConnectionFactory()
   {
      string connstr = $"server=awsrds;user=user;databse=mydb;KeepAlive=30";
      var datasourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDatasourceBuild(connstr) { ConnectionStringBuilder = { Password = null }}
         .UsePeriodicPasswordProvider((_,_) =>
            {
               string password = GeneratePostgresToken();
               return new ValueTask<string>(password);
            },
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         
      _npgSqlDatasource = datasourceBuilder.Build();
   }

   public async Task<IDBConnection> GetConnectionAsync()
   {
      return await _npgSqlDatasource.OpenConnectionAsync(); 
   }

   private string GeneratePostgresToken(){
      // call aws rds and get the token
   }
}

public class UserRepo(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory): IUserRepo
{
   public async Task<User> GetUser(){
      using IDBConnection connection = await connectionFactory.GetConnectionAsync();
      ...
      return await connection.QueryFirstOrDefault();
   }
}


DI
service.AddSingleton<IConnectionFactory, ConnectionFactory>();
service.AddTrasnsient<IUserRepo, UserRepo>();

However, for some reason, I have to provide a new password every 15 minutes, even though KeepAlive is enabled. I then found the UsePeriodicPasswordProvider option provided by the Npgsql library, and it seems to work as expected, generating a new password every 10 minutes.

What’s wrong with my code that could be causing the physical
connection to close? Or is it on the server side? Can I make any log improvements to the above code to detect that?
If I use UsePeriodicPasswordProvider, wouldn’t this create a new connection pool every 10 minutes while keeping the old pool (due to
the new token)?


Cross-posted as a github issue, conversation ongoing there.
